# Filter through wordpress nav_menu_css_class for all Instances of menu-item-

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to filter through the `$classes` array of the wordpress `wp_nav_menu` function and i can't figure out what I need to accomplish to get all instances of the menu-item classes.

For instance be able to filter through all the classes and check for `menu-item-*` occurrences.